# How to extract the points from a graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,3,6,8,14,20]

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

The above plot has different slopes, I want to get 100 number of points from the graph, can any one help me to find the points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find 100 points on your curve you will have to interpolate the data. One way of doing this is to use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, the documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,3,6,8,14,20]

f = interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
xnew = np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],100)

plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.plot(xnew, f(xnew))

plt.show()
```

In order to check that you have 100 points:

```
print (xnew.shape)
print (f(xnew).shape)
#(100,)
#(100,)
```

[image]